# How to use jQuery to log values to Firebug Console?

Tags: jquery, debugging, firefox, firebug

I just wonder if there is a way to use jQuery to log some variable values to Firebug console for debugging purpose?

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery? Just use `console.log()` http://getfirebug.com/logging

Answer (score 12, accepted):

jQuery is just a library for JavaScript, so you can just use the [`console.log()`](http://getfirebug.com/logging) function:

```
console.log(myVar);
```

Answer (score 8):

```
(function($) {
    $.log = function() {
       if( 'console' in window )
            console.log.apply(null, arguments);
    };
}(jQuery));


$.log("hello world, I'm just kidding with this answer, please upvote it anyway!");
$.log("You should really just call console.log() directly");
$.log("Over and out!");
```

Comment: Actually, while it's stupid to involve jQuery in this in any way, a helper function which checks that console exists before writing to it is a good idea. You don't want your js code to stop working because there is no developer console (eg. in old IE).

Answer (score 1):

It's not jquery, just Firebug API:

```
console.log(2,4,6,8,"foo",bar)
```