# jquery how to figure out what the JSON Object contains

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm using JQuery with CodeIgniter PHP to figure make AJAX calls and return data via JSON. I want to figure out what my JSON object has returned, but I'm not sure what the syntax might be. Is there a way to just alert or log all the contents of the JSON object somehow? This is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: groups_url,
    success: function(parent){
        alert (parent);
    }
});
```

If I do this - I get an object, but I don't know what it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Learn to love the Javascript console.  The `console.log` method covers almost every eventuality -- giving you a nicely formatted summary of the object (or array, string, number, or boolean) that you're concerned with.

```
console.log(parent);
```

You can see the log by a console built into your browser (e.g. Chrome console, the Firefox 4 web console, IE developer tools) or by using a plugin (e.g. Firebug for Firefox <4).

Comment: Ah - okay - so if it returns an array of objects, I use console.log(parent[i].property)

Answer (score 1):

[Log to your console and inspect it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969279/how-to-use-jquery-to-log-values-to-firebug-console):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: groups_url,
    success: function(parent){
       console.log(parent);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `groups_url` is returning json, you could just point your browser to that url and check out the response.

You can also use firebug or the dev console in chrome. Simply go to the network tab and you should see the ajax requests listed there along with the relevant headers and response.

Answer (score 0):

In your code to return the Json object you should be setting certain properties of an object, or dynamically creating an object, or something along those lines.

Can we see the method that returns the Json?

Say you are returning an object with the property `Id`, you should just be able to get that by accessing:

```
parent.Id
```

on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebug and set a breakpoint in the success method, then you'll be able to look at the json object.

Answer (score 0):

I use this piece of code, please notice the error function which will trigger if the request was not successful. (ie error 500 on the server side)

```
jQuery.ajax(
        {
            url: "http://yoururl/bla",
            success: function (data) { console.log(data); },
            error: function (data) { console.log(data); },
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            data: { name: "value", name2: "this will be posted in the request" }
        });
```